# Build tensorflow with bazel don't produce static library files?

Tags: tensorflow, static-libraries, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I built tensorflow with bazel in `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.4-gpu-py3`, bazel produce static library files automatically, for example, it generates `bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/libautotuning_proto_cc_impl.pic.a`
Then I use `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.4-py3` docker image to build tensorflow with bazel, now bazel doesn't produce those static files for me, how come ? What should I do to make bazel produce these static files for me ? I need these static files, not only tesorflow_cc.so and tensorflow_framework.so.

Answer (score -1):

What is the real options applied when running `bazel build` ?